# CSS/XHTML - what does the overlay.png do in this template?

Tags: css, templates, xhtml

http://html5up.net/big-picture

The overlay.png does make my background brighter. But I do not want to deleted it unless I understand what this png does. Do you guys have a clue?

The overlay.png is used here:

```
     #intro {
      background: url('images/overlay.png'), url('../images/intro.jpg');
      background-size: 256px 256px cover;
      background-attachment: fixed, fixed;
      background-position: top left, top center;
      background-repeat: repeat, no-repeat;
      color: #c2b090;
     }

.image:before 
{
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background: url('images/overlay.png');
}
```

Comment: Instead of providing the link make some screenshot and mark what is the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's making your background image lighter. overlay.png is a partially transparent blue-ish graphic that overlays intro.jpg. It's set as the first background image of your main section tags. If you delete it, your big images will not be washed out, but it will result in a failed HTTP request because your CSS is still referencing it. If you want to delete the image, you should remove reference to it in your style.css file if you can.